# Differences between the service Mesh projects Istio and Conduit

Tags: microservices, istio

***" 2018: The Year of Service Mesh "***

Recently, I did some research on the service Mesh for handling service-to-service communication, and the implementations created in the last two years. But I'm still so confused about the real **differences** between *Istio* and *Conduit* that already give the same features.

So it is obvious that they are competitors but, based on what, we can choose, as clients, the project that we should take?

Answer (score 1):

Both technologies provide service mesh communication, and developed with  plugin architecture, the list includes Prometheus,Zipkin etc.

As far as features are concerned, they will be at feature parity if not now, but at some point in the future. Especially with Kubernetes etc, you can always replace one with other without affecting your services much.

I would go with Istio if your services are based on Kubernetes as both are backed by Google, and expect them to work much better compared to Conduit going forward.

Last I read Istio will be supported on Docker Swarm as well, so it all depends where you are running your services and which mesh framework is most suited for it.

Comment: Conduit is a Red Hat offering so it is given preference in OpenShift and Red Hat community.